# how to find lastlog details in solaris

Tags: solaris, last

I need the equivalent command of linux lastlog in solaris, need to write a script to find the the users last login date and time in solaris servers. Linux its very easy to fetch using lastlog command.

I tried last -1 USERID , if any user not logged in that server then there is no ouptut , the task is to find the users who not logged in server more that 90 days, a script should give the output as

```
ServerName USERID 10-Jun-2018 3Days
```

Comment: This might help. https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/97595/can-i-change-the-output-format-of-the-last-command-to-display-the-year

Comment: am able to get the last logged in date using the following command 
    `finger $USER | sed -n 3p`
    `Last login Mon Apr  3, 2017 on pts/1 from abc_server`

Comment: am able to get the last logged in date using the following command 
    `finger $USER | sed -n 3p`
Below is the output from here am able to get the day,month and year which I can convert to epoch using perl and subtract from current date, 
    `Last login Mon Apr  3, 2017 on pts/1 from abc_server`

The new issue is, if any user logged in date is less than 6 months, then the year is not visible, how to get get the epoch for this date 
`Last login Wed Dec 27 12:32 on pts/1 from abc_server`

Comment: Looking at the other post, it shows the user's login time using epoch time.  You can try `date +"%s"` to get the current epoch time (in seconds) then subtract 90 days from that and filter with awk.

Comment: Source for finger is [here](https://github.com/illumos/illumos-gate/blob/master/usr/src/cmd/cmd-inet/usr.bin/finger.c)

Answer (score 7):

There is no direct equivalent to the Linux `lastlog` command, that is supplied with the operating system.

In the Linux login accounting system there is a table that records the last login time of each user account, indexed by that account's user ID.  In the NetBSD, FreeBSD, and OpenBSD login accounting systems, there is an equivalent table (albeit with a different structure and name), and (in the NetBSD and FreeBSD systems) a `lastlogin` command that dates from the middle 1990s.  In both the Linux and BSD worlds, this table is updated by the same programs that write the login log table and the currently active logins table, two other tables in the login database.

Solaris has two tables: an equivalent one, and one that is not quite equivalent.

The `last` command, that other people are pointing to, is not particularly useful because it does not operate from either one.  It operates off a *different* table in the login accounting database, the log of login events table; and as you can see if an account has never logged in there will be nothing in that table to process.  Whereas, in contrast, with the last login time table there is a record (on the BSDs an empty implicit one, on Linux an explicit empty one) for every user account.

The Solaris table that is not quite equivalent is `/var/adm/acct/sum/loginlog`.  This is not directly populated by the `login` program as logins happen, and there is no directly equivalent program for reporting on it.

It is associated with a `lastlogin` command; however, that is quite different to the aforementioned command by that name.  On Solaris, it is a tool for writing to this table rather than a tool for reporting upon its contents.  (This is also what `lastlogin` is for on AIX.) The `runacct` tool, run daily, invokes the `lastlogin` command to populate this table.  Reporting is done with the `prtacct` command.

The Solaris table that is directly equivalent is `/var/adm/lastlog`, which is not mentioned in Oracle doco.  There is no program supplied for reading it.  However, there was (until the software died at Oracle) a third party `lastlog` program written by Richard Hamilton available.  You might like to convince the OpenIndiana/Illumos people to incorporate such a command.  Dan McDonald, OmniOS engineer, was touching this stuff as recently as January 2016.

## Further reading

- Jonathan de Boyne Pollard (2018). *[The Unix login database](http://jdebp.eu./FGA/unix-login-database.html)*.  Frequently Given Answers.
- "[System Accounting Files](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23823_01/html/817-0403/sysresacctref-24103.html)".  *System Administration Guide: Advanced Administration*.  Oracle Solaris 10 8/11 Information Library.  Oracle.  2011.
- [lastlog](https://blogs.oracle.com/solaris/lastlog-v3). Oracle Solaris Blog.  2010-07-15.
- [`lastlogin`](https://freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=lastlogin&format=html). *FreeBSD System Manager's Manual*.  2011-06-06.
- [`last`](https://illumos.org/man/1/last).  *User Commands Manual*.  Illumos.  2017-04-12.
- [`acctsh`](https://www.unix.com/man-page/opensolaris/1M/acctsh/). *System Administration Commands*. SunOS 5.11.  2002-03-15.

Comment: Thank you, I wish there would be more answers like this one. Informative, thorough, with extra comparative notes. Kudos!

Answer (score 2):

The command for that in Solaris is `last`.

This will show you the last time the user `tim` logged in.

```
bash-[510]$ last -1 tim
tim       pts/1        192.168.0.106    Wed Jun 13 18:16   still logged in
```

If that user hasn't logged in since the db has been rotated, you won't get any output.

```
bash-[511]$ last -1 tom

wtmp begins Fri Mar 27 19:57
```

Answer (score 0):

Oracle Solaris also offers a nice tool called

## acct

You can find a description on the following link [Sytem Accounting](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E23823_01/html/817-0403/enmzl.html#scrolltoc).

In the directory **/var/adm/acct/sum** you will find a file called **loginlog**. This file record the last date each user logged in and is created by the **lastlogin script**.

Based on this file and using e.g. awk it should be very simple to fullfill your requires.